# Keep guest time after shutdown using KVM/libvirt

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization, centos6, libvirt

I use KVM/libvirt based virtualization. Some of vm guests have set date far in future (2-3 years, different month, day, etc) After each guest shutdown down, the date is being set to host date (kvmclock works that way).

Is there any possibility to keep date during guest shutdown? It should work even guest won't shutdown gracefully (crash, etc).

Guest and host are recent version of centos 6.4.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is stop using `kvm-clock`. To switch to another clocksource, edit your grub configuration and add `hpet=force` to the kernel boot line, to make it even more stable, you can also add a failover clocksource as follows: `clocksource_failover=acpi_pm`